# AngularJS videogular not responsive

Tags: angularjs, videogular

I am using angularjs and I read that videoangular is automatically responsive  with vg-responsive='true'.
But using this code:

```
<videogular vg-responsive='true'>
    <video class='videoPlayer' controls preload='none' vg-responsive='true'>
        <source src='http://www.videogular.com/assets/videos/videogular.mp4'  type='video/mp4'> 
    </video>
</videogular>
```

the video on the browser is not responsive.
Any idea?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a $scope variable like `config.responsive` instead of `true` directly?

I don't remember now, but maybe you can't set a value directly to vg-responsive.

**UPDATE**

You must specify a theme, this is a required parameter. This worked for me:

```
<videogular vg-theme="config.theme.url" vg-responsive="true">...</videogular>
```

You could take a look to the Videogular's reference for more info:
https://github.com/2fdevs/videogular/wiki/Videogular-reference

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I tried  with a $scope variable but does not work.

Comment: Did you specified the theme? It is required. Could you please post some code? I've tested and it worked for me.